# Insert print_r output into MySQL

Tags: php, arrays

I have this output in a text file (dump.log) from a remote server. where I don't have access to the original PHP-created array:

```
Array
(
    [email] => ddiar@beu.ac.il
    [timestamp] => 1369735202
    [smtp-id] => <1369735199.51as4801fed0f7@www.pub.org>
    [category] =>  decision 
    [event] => processed
)
Array
(
    [email] => jc@open.com
    [timestamp] => 1369735202
    [smtp-id] => <1369735199.51a4801fed0f7@www.open.org>
    [category] => Interm 
    [event] => processed
)
Array
(
    [email] => ilgkliar@bku.ac.il
    [timestamp] => 1369735204
    [smtp-id] => <1369735199.51ahg4801fed0f7@www.open.org>
    [response] => 250 OK: <ed628ghjbf2000aec70@bkju.ac.il> 
    [category] => decision 
    [event] => delivered
)
```

Now I would like to insert the values into MySQL table using PHP. (Like email_field, time_field,category_field..and so on.)

I tried function print_r_reverse from [here](https://www.php.net/print_r) but no luck.
Please provide complete code.

Comment: Iterating through the array shouldn't be hard. Did you try it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are happy to help you fix problems in your code, but this site is not designed to encourage others to write your code or development plan for you. Please feel free to improve this question or ask a new one when you have a specific, code-related problem.

Comment: `print_r` output is not exactly well suited for parsing. Why can't you use a proper data serialization format?

Comment: What did print_r return? Have you tried print_r with second parameter (return) set to true?

Comment: `print_r` is **not intended as a serialisation format**. It is **not possible** to perfectly reconstruct a PHP data structure from the `print_r` output. You may be able to do so in some cases, but it isn't intended for that, and there are some cases where it cannot be done. There certainly isn't an official way to do it. The `print_r_reverse` function that you've already tried is probably the best option available to you; if that doesn't work, you may well be stuck. If possible, I recommend changing the logging format to something that can be reconstructed.

Comment: By the way -- what exactly was the problem with the `print_r_reverse` function that you tried? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: You've not shown anything that you've tried, any code you've written, any details of the database you're inserting into, any details of the OS you're working on, any details of the tools you have available to you etc. Until you put some effort in, don't expect a free ride on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use **print_r**? For your purpose **var_export** is more adapted.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

> Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Instead I probably use **json_encode** and **json_decode**

Check first if your PHP support JSON.

Comment: Thank you var_export is worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

- Use `sed` and `awk` to extract the data into a CSV file which can then be
  imported into a database using `LOAD DATA LOCAL`
- Write PHP code which will take each line, look for specific features on each line and then create an array which can be imported into a database using whatever PHP MySQL commands you like (but not `mysql_` ones as they're deprecated)
- Pay someone to write the code for you

Either way, I;m guessing that Regular Expressions will be involved.

The fact that you've not shown anything you've attempted means that you've come to the wrong place if you want someone to write the code for you.